# How do I change the display of my results from one with white-space back to table view?

Tags: sql-server

Instead of showing the normal table/grid-like view, it's just showing me white spaces. Is there a way to change back to default settings?

[image]

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Comment: Since this doesn't appear to have anything whatsoever to do with Java and the screenshot shows SQL Server, I took the liberty of changing your tags appropriately. If the question is indeed about Java, feel free to fix the tags, but also tell us more about your problem and include some code.

Comment: oh snap, I forgot to change the tag. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Use *ResultsToGrid* option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), then rerun the query.

[image]